# PHP doesn't load xml from web until I load it using browser

Tags: php, xml

I use this code to download and parse xml file (currency rates):

```
        $url = "http://www.boi.org.il/currency.xml";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
        echo '<tr><td>الدولار</td><td>'.$xml->CURRENCY[0]->RATE.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>اليورو</td><td>'.$xml->CURRENCY[3]->RATE.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>الباوند</td><td>'.$xml->CURRENCY[1]->RATE.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>دينار اردني</td><td>'.$xml->CURRENCY[11]->RATE.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>جنيه مصري</td><td>'.$xml->CURRENCY[13]->RATE.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>ليرة لبنانية</td><td>'.$xml->CURRENCY[12]->RATE.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>الين الياباني</td><td>'.$xml->CURRENCY[2]->RATE.'</td></tr>';
```

But php doesn't load file!! When I go to chrome browser and view the link there THEN the php works fine... Why the php doesn't load file?

I use IIS 7.5 Windows server 2008 R2 64 bit

Thank you

Comment: It's expecting a cookie named `rrrrrrr`. The initial load in your browser sets the cookie via JavaScript and reloads the page. You'll have to use an HTTP client in PHP that supports cookies.

Comment: You can do it with `curl`. Download the page once, find the cookie in the Javascript, then download the page again, with the cookie in `CURLOPT_COOKIE` to send back the cookie.

Comment: Then use `simplexml_load_string` to load the XML from the second result.

Comment: @Barmar Seems to be some IP tracking or something as the cookie isn't required on subsequent requests which is why OP's PHP works after they visit in their browser

Comment: Sending the cookie with `curl` didn't work for me. But I see the IP tracker -- after I accessed the page with my browser, it worked with curl.